# When I delete an item from the database and updatethe datagrid, I still see this object

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq

I have two windows wpf.
On the first window I see data from DataGrid, on the second window I delete object from database.

First window:

```
private void mnRemoveProduct_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   RemoveProduct window = new RemoveProduct();
   window.ShowDialog();
   ShowWatchTable();
} // mnRemoveProduct_Click
```

Second window:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbNameOfWatch.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        var value =
            (from watch in obj.Watch.Where(w => w.mark == cmbNameOfWatch.SelectedValue.ToString())
             select new { watch.id }).ToArray().First();

        Watch watchObj = obj.Watch.Find(value.id);
        obj.Watch.Remove(watchObj);
        obj.SaveChanges();

        this.Close();
    }
} // btnDelete_Click
```

and function ShowTable

```
public void ShowWatchTable()
{
    obj.Watch.ToList();
    dataGrid.ItemsSource =
        from watch in obj.Watch.Local
        select new
        {
            ID = watch.id,
            Brand = watch.mark,
            Typ = watch.TypeWatch.typeName,
            Price = watch.price + " $".ToString(),
            Quantity = watch.number,
            Fabricator = watch.Fabricator.fName,
            Country = watch.Fabricator.Country.countryName
        };
}
```

When I delete value from database, I still see this value in DataGrid. Only when I close and open this form then I no longer see this object. When I add an element, the same logic is used. Datagrid is updated with the ShowTable function and I see the updated database. But when deleting it it does not work. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you are deleting from `obj.Watch` using

```
obj.Watch.Remove(watchObj);
obj.SaveChanges();
```

but when refreshing your list, you are binding to `obj.Watch.Local` which I assume is a local cache of your datasource. I don't see where you are syncing this so you might want to sync that before binding or perform your operations on the local sync and ensure that it sends it's changes to the remote data source.

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: I have it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, my guess your data source is a query result, but i'm not pretty sure that it's observable(f.e. when I need to bind to collections, I use IObservableCollection to notify that collection changed).
Probably you can try to call `dbGrid.Items.Refresh();` method when your primary views gets focus back

Comment: it does not help

Answer (score 1):

You just need to manually refresh your DataGrid.
Add this after your datasource is updated:

```
dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

Comment: it does not help

Comment: @EmmaW. I don't see from your code that you are calling `ShowWatchTable()` for the first Window after the Item was deleted from the Second Window

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure the collection backing the source of your data items implements INotifyCollectionChanged.

[MSDN link to docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx), also copied relevant section here.

Binding to Data

To bind the DataGrid to data, set the ItemsSource property to an IEnumerable implementation. Each row in the data grid is bound to an object in the data source, and each column in the data grid is bound to a property of the data object. In order for the DataGrid user interface to update automatically when items are added to or removed from the source data, the DataGrid must be bound to a collection that implements the INotifyCollectionChanged interface, such as an ObservableCollection. To automatically reflect property changes, the objects in the source collection must implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. For more information, see Data Binding (WPF).